# Why can't I see details of deleted answers?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, deleted-users, sock-puppets, abuse

[On this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63709936/how-exactly-do-i-render-metal-on-a-background-thread), I posted some comments, and later a full answer. The OP and I had some normal back-and-forth discussion in the comments.

I later noticed that there were two deleted answers, which I originally thought were by OP but seemingly were by other new users, and the OP's account itself was gone. The questions each have **-7 score**, which I find very odd, as the original question and my answer both got little attention and 0 votes.

[image]

The answers were marked as spam/abusive, but that seems incongruous with the OP's perfectly respectful and normal question and comments. I can't see whether the answers were actually spam even if I go to their revision history:

[image]

What really happened here?

(As a side note, each of the OP's comments is for some reason wrapped in a link that points at my answer or the comment to which they were replying. Is there any explanation for this other than that the OP manually typed out the Markdown necessary to make their comments into links — which seems unlikely to me, since it would be eminently clear what they were replying to?)

Comment: That you first thought that OP wrote those comments like to me like they all had the same name, maybe also the same avatar so you thought it was the same account. Since they were different accounts, I assume OP created multiple accounts. It is unusual that one uses different accounts for each comment and that the comments look like that, so I wouldn't be surprised if they used a script to create the accounts and generate the comments with a given text. I also assume that this script "went rogue" and posted answers instead of comments which OP tried to fix by manually deleting the content.

Comment: *Answers* from new users go to "First posts" queue - it is not very surprising if some very rude (or even completely pointless) stuff got plenty of votes there... If moderators got involved they may cleaned up the history if it was really over the top...

Comment: Actually, I saw most of these comments after the users were deleted, so they all looked like "user123456789" and that's why I didn't notice the difference. I don't think OP intentionally tried to make the accounts look like the same user. I also found it strange that the number of votes on these two answers was exactly the same, since presumably they wouldn't be exactly in the same place in the queue, and not everyone reviewing answers in the queue would click through to see both answers on the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I not sure, but as far as I know only developers can edit a post without adding a new revision by doing that directly on the database. And that rarely happens, especially for deleted posts which are only available to a limited group of users. That is why I assumed in my comment above that the user writing the answer(s) deleted the content themselves.

Comment: @jtbandes Since you mentioned confusing comment screen names, I thought I'd mention; I use a userscript to help me identify unique authors in comments, if you'd like [to take a look](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#comment-user-colors) (It's not my script). It makes following comment threads loads easier for me, since it helps distinguish similar looking screen names, and might've helped in this case in identifying who was unique.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answers that have been deleted as spam or offensive content are not automatically displayed on the page, even for users with privileges to see deleted posts. Instead, as shown in your screenshots, you have to click the link to the revision history in order to actually see the content. This is because we want to protect you from seeing spam or abusive content unless you specifically opt in. (Moderators don't have to opt in. We always see spam or abusive content inlined on the page. We cannot get away.)

Indeed, when you click to see the revision history, you see the two answers in their original form:

[image]

A couple of things to note here:

1. You're not missing anything interesting.
2. The body of the answers themselves actually contain the gibberish "[Deleted][Deleted][Deleted]"...etc. That was submitted by the original poster. It was *not* automatically inserted by the system. The system doesn't do that. This type of gibberish is a good clue as to why the posts were nuked by a moderator as spam/abusive content.
3. Both answers were posted by separate user accounts, which you can tell based on the anonymized ID of the deleted user.
4. Mods see slightly different stuff on their pages, especially when they are running userscripts in their browsers that add even more stuff.

As to why you can't see the actual content in the revision history for either of the two answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64363001/revisions) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64363014/revisions)), that's because the edits to replace the text with gibberish were submitted by the original poster *within the 5-minute grace period*. Edits that are submitted within the 5-minute grace period are not tracked separately in the revision history, unless there was a comment or something that disrupts the grace period interval. (Supposedly, the initial revision *is* stored in the database, but not even moderators can see that. It requires a developer with database access. I'm absolutely confident that there's nothing in either of these answers worth the effort in bothering a developer to retrieve. In other words, see point #1 above.)

Comment: Also highly suspicious that the two user names are numerically only 6 apart from each other

Comment: I *think* it's documented that user IDs are assigned sequentially, so not really all that suspicious, @charlietfl.

Comment: feature of hiding spam/rude answers from 10Kers like that was [implemented in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199969/165773)

Comment: @CodyGray: and both brand new users spotted this question, answered it, and then decided to replace the content by the same string.